# Closed form expression for the number of ordered pairs $\{A, B\}$, where $A, B \subseteq \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ such that $|A \cap B| = 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

What is a closed form expression for the number of  ordered pairs $\{A, B\}$, where $A, B \subseteq \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ such that $|A \cap B| = 1$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First choose some element $i$ to be in both $A$ and $B$, which can be done in $n$ ways. For the rest of the members of $\{1,2,...,n\}\setminus \{i\}$, they are either in $A$ or $B$ or neither, so there are $3$ options for each. Since there are $n-1$ elements left, there are $3^{n-1}$ ways to assign the remaining elements.

Together, this gives us a total of $n3^{n-1}$ such ordered pairs.

Comment: And more generally the answer is $\binom nk3^{n-k}$ if the condition $|A\cap B|=1$ is changed to $|A\cap B|=k.$

Comment: Even more generally, we can look at ordered tuples of $c$ sets, so there are $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom n i = 2^n - 1$ possible choices for the rest of the members (choose for it to be in at most $n-1$ of the sets), so we get $\binom n k (2^n -1)^{n-k}$.

Comment: (sorry, should be $2^c-1)